# Related to developing a SNMP extension agent DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, snmp

I am following the tutorial below to create an extension agent DLL. I am following the tutorial below: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SNMP_Agent_DLL__Part1_.aspx

According to the tutorial, I am required to use these 1 of  method signatures at a minimum among others:

```
BOOL SNMP_FUNC_TYPE SnmpExtensionQuery(BYTE bPduType, 
                SnmpVarBindList *pVarBindList, 
                AsnInteger32 *pErrorStatus, 
                AsnInteger32 *pErrorIndex)
```

The issue is with **SnmpVarBindList *pVarBindList** parameter. I am suppossed to insert the following data e.g ("About", "Name", "Age") into the SnmpVarBindList datatype and than pass it into the method above...

**but I am not sure how to create the list of SnmpVarBindList datatype and insert the following data e.g ("About", "Name", "Age") into the list??**

```
MIB_ENTRY g_MyMibTable[] = {
{   
    {OID_SIZEOF(g_unAboutOid),g_unAboutOid},
    &g_szAbout,
    "About",
    ASN_OCTETSTRING,
    SNMP_ACCESS_READ_ONLY,
    &g_MyMibTable[1]
},
{
    {OID_SIZEOF(g_unNameOid),g_unNameOid},
    &g_szName,
    "Name",
    ASN_OCTETSTRING,
    SNMP_ACCESS_READ_WRITE,
    &g_MyMibTable[2]
},
{
    {OID_SIZEOF(g_unAgeOid),g_unAgeOid},
    &g_asnIntAge,
    "Age",
    ASN_INTEGER,
    SNMP_ACCESS_READ_WRITE,
    NULL
}
```

};

==========================================================================================
// struct definations for your reference:

```
typedef struct {
AsnObjectName    name;
AsnObjectSyntax  value;
```

} SnmpVarBind;

```
typedef struct {
SnmpVarBind * list;
UINT          len;
```

} SnmpVarBindList;

**Any guidance or code example provided will be much appreciated, I am new to C++**

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need.

```
/* Définitions of vars leaves.
    Terminal zero is needed
*/       
UINT MIB_About[]     = { 2, 1, 0 };
UINT MIB_Name[]      = { 2, 2, 0 };
UINT MIB_Age[]       = { 2, 3, 0 };

/* Physical (Har-coded) data of the MIB
*/
char       MIB_AboutStor[]     = "The about text";
char       MIB_NameStor[]      = "The Name text";
AsnInteger MIB_AgeStor         = 20;
extern MIB_ENTRY Mib[];
extern UINT      MIB_num_variables;

/* initialisation du modèle d'accès aux variables de la MIB 
*/
MIB_ENTRY Mib[] = {
      { { OID_SIZEOF(MIB_About), MIB_About },
        &MIB_AboutStor, ASN_RFC1213_DISPSTRING,
        MIB_ACCESS_READ, MIB_leaf_func, &Mib[1] },

      { { OID_SIZEOF(MIB_Name), MIB_Name },
        &MIB_NameStor, ASN_RFC1213_DISPSTRING,
        MIB_ACCESS_READ, MIB_leaf_func, &Mib[2] },

      { { OID_SIZEOF(MIB_Age), MIB_Age },
        &MIB_AgeStor, ASN_INTEGER,
        MIB_ACCESS_READWRITE, MIB_control_func, NULL }
      };

UINT MIB_num_variables = sizeof Mib / sizeof( MIB_ENTRY );
```

You can finf `MIB_leaf_func` and `MIB_control_func` in Microsoft Example.

Comment: thank you JP. Also how instead of having the values hardcoded I would need to call the BOOL SNMP_FUNC_TYPE SnmpExtensionQuery(BYTE bPduType, SnmpVarBindList *pVarBindList, AsnInteger32 *pErrorStatus, AsnInteger32 *pErrorIndex) inside the SnmpExtensionInit method correct??